# Find diagonals ratio in a trapezium

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a trapezium with $AB \parallel CD$ and $m(\measuredangle BAD) = \frac{\pi}{2}$. We also know that $2AB = CD$ and $AC \perp BD$. Find $\frac{AC}{BD}$.

By using the Pythagorean theorem I found the following:
$$\left( \frac{AC}{BD} \right)^2 = \frac{AD^2 + 4AB^2}{AD^2 + AB^2}$$
$$AC^2 + BD^2 = 2AD^2 + 5AB^2$$

That's all I could find. I don't know how to proceed from this point.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have what is called a "rectangular trapezoid" (http://math-formulas.com/geometric-shapes/2d-shapes/trapezoid/lateral-faces-of-a-rectangular-trapezoid.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Let $BE||AC$ and $BF\perp CD$. Then in triangle $EBD$ $DB\perp BE$ and $CF=FD=CE=AB=x$.

$$BF^2=DF \cdot EF =x \cdot 2x = 2x^2$$ Then $BF=\sqrt2 x$

$$BE=AC=\sqrt{2x^2+4x^2}=\sqrt6 x$$
$$BD=\sqrt{x^2+2x^2}=\sqrt3x$$
Then $$\frac{AC}{BD}=\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt3}=\sqrt2$$

Comment: Well, the issue is that $BF^2 \neq 3x^2$ but $BF^2 = 2x^2$. And no need of Pythagoras' theorem, triangles $DFB$ and $DBE$ are similar, so $AC : BD = BE : BD = BF : DF = \sqrt{2} x : x = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Futurologist: Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I make such mistakes too (and probably more frequently than you).

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement the answer above, which does not explain why $BF^2=DF\cdot EF$. This is because $\triangle DBE\sim \triangle DFB (AAA)$ which gives
$$
\frac{BF}{BE} = \frac{DF}{BD} = \frac{BD}{DE}
$$
Therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
BF^2 &= BD^2-DF^2\\ &=DF\cdot DE-DF^2\\ &=DF(DE-DF)\\ &=DF\cdot EF
\end{aligned}
$$
Finally again by similarity of the two triangles,
$$
\frac{AC}{BD} = \frac{BE}{BD} = \frac{BF}{DF} =\frac{\sqrt{DF\cdot FE}}{DF}= \frac{\sqrt{2DF^2}}{DF} = \sqrt{2}
$$